# Prove that only principal filters will have the infinite intersection property.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory, filters

Let, $X$ be an infinite set. And also let $X=\{x_i:i\in\mathbb{N}\}$. I have considered a filter defined on $X$ but it doesn't have the infinite intersection property. The filter that I considered is
$$\mathscr{F}(X)=\{S\subseteq X: X\setminus S<\infty\}$$
Where by $X\setminus S<\infty$, I mean that $X\setminus S$ is finite. Using the axioms of filters I showed that the following set is a filter and doesn't have the infinite intersection property.

**My question:-**

$(1)$- I was wondering if all filters with infinite collection of subsets from $X$, which doesn't have the infinite intersection property have something in common or they are some kind of filters. I am willing to know why and why not?

$(2)$- Secondly are there any filters on this infinite set $X$ which does have the infinite intersection property?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Eric Wofsey about the definition of "principal filter", but the first sentence of Robert Shore's answer is correct. To prove it, suppose $\mathcal F$ is a filter closed under arbitrary intersections, and let $A$ be the intersection of all the sets in $\mathcal F$. So the assumption implies that $A\in\mathcal F$, and from this (and the fact that $\mathcal F$ is a filter) it follows that $\mathcal F$ consists of exactly the supersets of $A$. So $\mathcal F$ is the principlal filter generated by $A$.

Comment: yes it can be proved when $A$ in your case refers to intersections of all elements of $\mathscr{F}$. But what if, an infinite subset of $\mathscr{F}$ is taken(Under assumption that $X$ is an infinite set and $\mathscr{F}$ is also infinite collection of subsets) and we do intersection of all elements of that infinite subset?

Comment: @B210108BORARAHULREDDY A non-principal filter may well contain the intersection of **some** infinitely many of its members. In fact, a non-principal ultrafilter will definitely contain some such intersections.

Comment: Could be please provide an example supporting your statement that non principal filters may contain intersection of infinitely many members of any infinite subset of it?

Comment: @B210108BORARAHULREDDY Let $U$ be a non-principal ultrafilter on $\mathbb N$. Let $A$ be the set of even numbers or the set of odd numbers, whichever is un $U$. Then, for every subset $X$ of $\mathbb N-A$, the union $A\cup X$ is in $U$, and the intersection of all these sets (for varying $X$) is $A$.

Comment: @Andreas Blass, I am sorry but I didn't get your example. Please elaborate it.

Comment: @RAHUL Sorry, but I don't see any more details to add; my previous comment looks to me like a complete proof. What don't you understand in it?

Answer (score 0):

No filter on the space of subsets other than a principal filter can possibly have the "infinite intersection property," if by that you mean that that the filter contains arbitrarily large intersections of filter elements.  To see this, for each $x \in X$ choose $A_x \in \mathscr F$ such that $x \notin A_x$.  Since by assumption $\mathscr F$ is not principal, it's always possible to find such an $A_x$ for any $x \in X$.

But then $$\bigcap_{x \in X} A_x = \varnothing.$$

This proves that no filter on the subsets of a countable set can be closed under the intersection of countably many filter elements.

The more interesting question is whether a filter on the subsets of $X$, where $\vert X \vert = \kappa \gt \omega$, can satisfy the $\lambda$-intersection property for any (or all) $\lambda \lt \kappa$.  The answer to that question turns out to be yes.

Comment: $\mathscr{F}$ not being principal does not imply that such an $A_x$ exists for any $x\in X$.  (It does for ultrafilters, but not for general filters.)

Comment: @EricWofsey a filter is principal iff it’s intersection is non-empty and non-principal otherwise. So the statement is almost a tautology.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: That's not true.  For instance, if $X$ is an infinite set and $x\in X$, you can take the filter consisting of all cofinite subsets of $X$ that contain $x$.  This filter is non-principal but its intersection is $\{x\}$.

Comment: @EricWofsey the intersection is $\{x\}$ so by definition it’s principal (or “fixed”). At least according to my books.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: I don't recall ever seeing that as the definition of "principal" for general filters (rather than just ultrafilters).  In my experience, a principal filter is defined as a filter generated by a single set.  (The two definitions are equivalent for ultrafilters.)

Comment: @EricWofsey I see your point.  I think that the comments are a valuable contribution to the original question, though, so I'm reluctant to delete the answer.