# The filter generated by $\mathcal{B} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(I)$ is non-principal if and only if $\mathcal{B}$ has the finite intersection property

Tags: set-theory, filters

Would it be possible for someone to confirm whether the following proposition is erroneous. It appears in a set of lecture notes on model theory and pertains to non-principal filters.

$\bf{Proposition}$: Let $I$ be a set and $\mathcal{B} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(I)$. The following are equivalent:

1. The filter generated by $\mathcal{B}$ is non-principal;
2. $\mathcal{B}$ has the finite intersection property, that is, if $\{B_1,...,B_n\} \subseteq \mathcal{B}$, then $\bigcap_{j = 1}^nB_j \neq \emptyset$.

Immediately before this, the author writes "the following proposition is immediate" and does not provide a proof. Since every proper filter has the finite intersection property, it seems to me that taking $\mathcal{B}$ to be any principal filter is an obvious counterexample, but perhaps I have misunderstood something along the way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Suggestion: just replace *non-principal* by *proper*.

Comment: See also the discussion about the definition of a principal filter in the comments to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4302506).

Comment: @J.-E.Pin So the author presumably intended to write *proper* rather than *non-principal*? That makes far more sense. It's unfortunate that I actually wasted time trying to prove (2) -> (1) before finally realizing that the "immediate" proposition was misstated. Thanks a lot for the clarification!